# How to hide url parameters in Next.js 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to hide query params or query parameter, i want to show custom url on naviagation in Next.js 14.
For example /user/12 expected output /user

Can anyone help me out here.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
const router = useRouter();
<DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => router.push(`${ASSESSMENTS}/answer-code?assessmentId=${assessment.id}`)} >Upload Answer</DropdownMenuItem>
```

Comment: Why would you do this? If you use query params than you have to submit them. Depending on your use case, you have options like dynamic routes (probably what you want to use), POST and not GET, perhaps rewrites. I guess you should rethink what you want to accomplish. Query params always show up in browsers.

Comment: Time has gone. Please select an answer or answer your question and select as resolved. This helps keep Stack Overflow tidy.

Answer (score 1):

With Dynamic Routes you could do:

```
`/some-path/answer-code/${assessment.id}`
```

The page file path would look like this:

```
/app/some-path/answer-code/[assessmentid]/page.js
```

Inside the page you have access to `assessmentid`. Read about [Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) for more options and great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a much simplier way and it's not nextjs specific but i would store the variables in localstorage. Add parameters to localstorage on click, remove parameters when task on second page is finished.